# Laravel Ajax Get and Post request using controller

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

i'm trying to change the **$MONTH** inside my controller from my view using ajax but i'm confuse on how to do this, should i use **POST** or **GET** method? and i want to use input or select html element please correct me if i'm doing this wrongly thanks.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function days(Request $request){
$days=array();
$id = $request->input('months');
$month = $id;
$year = 2018;
for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
$time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);  
if(date('m', $time)==$month && date('w', $time)>0 && date('w', $time)<6) {
$days[]=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
}}


$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});
ajax({
    url:'days',
    type: 'get',
    data: {

       months:1
    },
    success: function( data ){

        console.log(data);
    },
     });
```

**Route::**

```
Route::get('days', 'PivotController@days' );
```

Comment: show you HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`You can use ajax like that it will definetly work.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo url("/ajax-data-type");?>', // Url to which the request is send
    type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
    data:{"month":1,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
     success: function (response)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
          jQuery(".loader-wrapper").addClass('hide');
          $('#ajax_data').html(response);
           if(response.status == false){
              SITE.initNotifications('alert-danger', '', response.result);
              }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can get value from select box by using below code .

    var month;
    $(document).on('change','.check-type',function(){
     month = $(this).val();
    });

now use month variable in place of 1 it will become dynamic

Comment: Could You please paste your all code so that i can figure out.

Comment: I checked your code and found that you used id months and in js function you haven't change it to months you are using class check-type.
Please change .check-type to months